# Is pretérito perfeito composto widely used in modern European and Brazilian Portuguese?

Tags: português-brasileiro, português-europeu, tempo-verbal

While thinking over [this question in Latin community](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/331/6674) and pounding the differences in the use of composite past in French and Portuguese, I discovered that [conjugation tables](https://www.conjugacao.com.br/verbo-falar/), [discussions of Portuguese past tenses](https://www.portuguesepedia.com/portuguese-past-tenses/), or even [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_verb_conjugation) sometimes do not even mention the composite variety of simple past (*pretérito perfeito composto*, aka *eu tenho falado*), discuss only *pretérito perfeito* (*eu falei*).

Is this tense somehow less important or very rare in modern Portuguese? Or does it have to do with the differences between the European and Brazilian Portuguese?

Comment: I hope I understood your question correctly. That said, the problem is that in Portuguese our "perfect", despite existing, doesn't carry the same concept of perfect in English or in ancient Greek, where an action in the past still "reverberates" in the present. That said, for 98.74% of Portuguese speakers (source: Fakedata inc.) things like "eu falei" have no perfect tense meaning whatsoever. If you want to deliver the idea of the perfect tense, you use the composite: "eu tenho falado" (which means: I started speaking in the past but I'm still speaking in the present).

Comment: (continuation) Thus, it's not rare at all, it's very commonly used for giving the perfect tense idea. However, you won't find it in the conjugation tables (unlike those for English, that normally show the auxiliary verb) because their construction is trivial (for native speakers), as the [answer below](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/9460/11587) explains.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado *you won't find it in the conjugation tables (unlike those for English, that normally show the auxiliary verb) because their construction is trivial* - this is precisely what perturbed me, since the conjugation tables in French, English in German usually go through the trouble of showing all the composite tenses.

Comment: You are not using the right name for these verbs: they are called **tempos verbais compostos** and here you have them: https://www.conjugacao.com.br/tempos-verbais-compostos/ Those are called compound tenses, not composite. And in French, they say: **les temps composés**.

Answer (score 5):

No, it's not rare at all, even if it's of course not the most common tense.

I think this [conjugation website](https://conjuga-me.net/) gives the most common reason for conjugation tables to omit some or all of the compound tenses [1]:

> **Is the given verbal conjugation complete?**
>
> No.
>
> For compound tenses conjugation is not shown, since those are easily constructed from the verb's past participle and an auxiliary verb

In general, there is [a number](https://www.conjugacao.com.br/tempos-verbais-compostos/) of compound tenses (see also [here](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/tempos-compostos/8349)), as well as the so-called [locuções verbais](https://www.normaculta.com.br/locucoes-verbais/), which might look quite like tenses themselves, and they're all for the most part fairly commonly used.

---

[1] Freely translated from the [original](https://conjuga-me.net/):

> **A conjugação verbal apresentada está completa?**
>
> Não.
>
> Para os tempos compostos não aparece conjugação pois estes formam-se facilmente com o particípio passado do verbo e com um auxiliar

Comment: There is a number of [compound tenses](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/tempos-compostos/8349), but there are also the [_locuções verbais_](https://www.normaculta.com.br/locucoes-verbais/), which might look quite like tenses themselves.

Answer (score 2):

It is used! But there's a catch: it is not equivalent to the *pretérito perfeito simples* as it would be in other romance languages (or like it is with *mais-que-perfeito* (by the way, that's why one of them disappeared))!

If I say "*comprei uns carros*", it means "I bought some cars". But if I say "*tenho comprado uns carros*" it means "I have been buying some cars", so it refers to another aspectual meaning, something related to frequency!

And yes, conjugation tables usually only contain simples tenses, since they are usually used to show the endings in each tense, person and number.

So, it exists and it is used very often, but it just has a different meaning compared to other romance languages!

Comment: Tenho comprado uns carros. = I have bought some cars. Not: been buying. Tenho estado comprando carros ultimamente.

Comment: Not at all, @Lambie, are you a native speaker? If so it must be a very specific regional variation.

Comment: Nem sei o que responder. Mas isto: "But if I say "tenho comprado uns carros" it means "I have been buying some cars"" está errado. Tenho comprado uns carros = I have bought some cars. A palavra em inglês é *frequency". E é Romance languages, com maiúscula.

Comment: I think _I've been buying some cars_ is a reasonable translation (though it probably matches more closely _tenho andado a comprar uns carros_). Another possibility is _I've bought some cars lately_. I agree that _I've bought some cars_ is a worse translation. The point is that there is an idea of repetition, and the pattern of action must continue up to the present. You can say _I've bought this car at an auction_, but not _tenho comprado este carro num leilão_.

Comment: I would say that the biggest problem with "tenho comprado uns carros" and its translation is the determiner that comes with the noun. For me and for other speakers (from Brazil and Portugal) I asked, it seems to work just fine. I didn't want to use technical terms in my answer, but what the "pretérito perfeito composto" expresses is something called iteration (except when we have states, the opposite of an event) and this aspectual value is something "unique" to Portuguese when it comes to this specific construction. :)

Comment: @ErgativeMan certo, embora não seja o caso com verbos que exprimem estados, e.g. _desde que nasci que tenho vivido em Lisboa_.

Comment: @Artefacto exato!